# How can you get the touch location during scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiscrollview, touch

It seems that the UIScrollView stops sending touch events to the delegates on the scrollViewDidScroll event. I'm trying to get the y location and can't seem to find access to the events. I would like to update the view based on the position while it's scrolling.

The best lead I've had has been this ( http://github.com/andreyvit/ScrollingMadness ) but this doesn't quite answer my question.

Any pointers and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`-scrollViewDidScroll` is called with a reference to the UIScrollView that did the scrolling. Check out `[scrollView contentOffset]` to get the current scroll location.

Comment: That's pretty close but it only gives the x change in position and I would like to get the y. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: -contentOffset returns a CGPoint with x and y members. If the y is 0, you're at the top.